# Numbers: how to search only within a selected range?

Tags: numbers

I have a very big table, and searching for a string can take a few seconds. However, I only want to search in a particular column. Even when a column is selected, Numbers searches the entire table. How can I constrain the search to the selected column?

Comment: Very annoying you can replace text using a selection.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter data in numbers using filtering data , in that you can select the row/column set the rule , keyword to be searched can be set there itself. For more details [Link](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH17084?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: If nothing else exists I guess that'll have to do, but then I can't look at surrounding data if I want easily (since it's filtered). So no way to just constrain the search?

Comment: If you want a very hacky solution, just copy and paste the selection into a new document and do the search. e.g. I was just trying to count how many of a certain value there was, and that gave the answer instantly.